# reading html file to javascript variable (windows)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

hey,
I want to read an html file into a javascript variable that will contain it as a string.
is there an appropriate function, for example, that takes the file path as a parameter.

thanks

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/312a5kbt(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: you are looking to achieve this in winows desktop environment?

Answer (score 1):

Although `XMLHttpRequest` can be used to download entire pages, it is often used for downloading small pieces of data that can be used to update the current page.

Here is the basic to it:
[XMLHttpRequest](http://jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html)

This should help you jump start i hope.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest can be used in C# webbrowser object or should I use ActiveXObject?

Comment: i am not familiar with C# but you can retrive XMLHttpRequst through ActiveXObject for pre IE6 i believe.  Again, need more information on what you trying to achive